# Symfony 2 and swiftmailer, I can not send mail with gmail suit

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send symfony 2 a mail. I'm using google suite, I have a registered domain on aruba.it but use google mail for mail. It is a domain address, ie mail@mydomain.com. In the configuration file I have:

```
Auth_mode: login
     Transport: "% mailer_transport%"
     Encryption: "% mailer_encryption%"
     Host: "% mailer_host%"
     Port: "% mailer_port%"
     Username: "% mailer_user%"
     Password: "% mailer_password%"
     Sender_address: "% mailer_sender_address%"
```

In the parameter file, mailer_transport: smtp mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com. But the mail is not sent. Can someone help me? How can I debug? Is there a log file?

I have tried with mailer_transport: gmail in parameters and transport: gmail in config but don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following details in my `parameters`, it always seems to work. You might also want to read through their [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/gmail.html)

```
mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_auth_mode:  login
mailer_host:       smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user:   youremailaddress
mailer_password:   yourpassword
mailer_port:       465
```